# Read data from serial port in simulink

Tags: matlab, serial-port, string-formatting, simulink, packet

When I use `fscanf` in MATLAB code, I'm able to read data from a serial port. However, I cannot use this function in a 'Matlab function' block in Simulink. Therefore, I use 'packet input' and 'packet output' to send and receive data from serial port in Simulink, but then I cannot read string format in these blocks.

I use the following codes in MATLAB script:

```
gotoConfig = hex2dec({'00','6E'});
fwrite(s,gotoConfig);
R0 = 24*abs(fscanf(s,'%e',14))*2*pi/12000;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: In this question, our received data is in four byte package ( long integer). Since the nature of USB protocol is based on one byte format, therefore,we received four non-meaning byte data.

Comment: Would you please explain what _exactly_ is the problem you want help with? It looks like there are several things you could be having troubles with... Also, what do you mean by "read string format"?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: connected with USB protocol to PC. The output of  encoder is 4 bytes.  In mfile, we can receive  correct data using  'fscanf' command. but since we are interested to be ral time, we employed simulink. but in simulink the received data is meaningless.  we can not use 'fscanf' in simulink. what we should we do?   Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of the "meaningless data" that you are getting in Simulink, and what the expected data should look like. Perhaps you only have a problem with interpreting what you're getting.